# force IE9 and IE10 in different document modes

Tags: html, internet-explorer, meta-tags, meta

Im trying to get Quirks mode in IE10 and force IE9 in IE9 standard document mode.
I can get both in one mode but not each in separate modes.

Ive set:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

But this forces both IE version to the standards.

But IE9 needs to have standard document mode, while IE10 needs Quirk mode.

Ive tries setting:

```
<!--[if IE 9]>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<![endif]-->
```

So IE 10 doesnt get the standards mode, but to no avail.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Why would you want IE to go to quirks mode?

Comment: Because somehow the overflow of a table gets screwed up in IE10, an in Quirks mode everything works the way i want it to

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) Your real issue is why your page doesn't work in IE9 and 10. This may stick a sticking plaster over it for now but will likely cause you more issues in the future.

Comment: Then perhaps it's a better solution to actually fix the overflow of the table for IE10, instead of forcing the browser to an outdated, non-standard-compliant version of IE. Laziness is never a good solution. That gets you to the corner of people who use `<center>` tags and `align=""` attributes.

Comment: sadly our users work exclusivly in IE 9 and some in IE 10 browsers.

Comment: even more reason to fix the actual problem!!!

Comment: This is like writing a 16-bit DOS program then trying to get it to work natively on Windows 8.